# writting to a shared variable in different threads don't provoque data race with openMP

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I am currently learning openMP basics, so I picked a simple exercise and start solving: I am given a  implementation of a serial program that approximate the value of Pi and I am asked to give it's parallel implementation.

serial program :

```
static long num_steps = 100000;
double step;
void main ()
{           
    int i;   
    double x, pi, sum = 0.0;
    step = 1.0/(double) num_steps;
    for (i=0;i< num_steps; i++){
         x = (i+0.5)*step;
         sum = sum + 4.0/(1.0+x*x);
    }
    pi = step * sum;
}
```

it's computing an approximation to the integral of 4.0/(1+x²) dx over the interval of 0 to 1.

The tutorial is using an incremental approach, giving a little chunk in each step, so for now, I am allowed to use the parallel construct with some runtime functions.

for me the obvious thing to do is to divide and perform partial summation. Here is my solution:

```
int main()
{
    const long num_steps = 100000;
    double step;
    double pi, sum = 0.0;
    step = 1.0/(double) num_steps;
    int num_steps_perthread = num_steps/4;
    double start_time = omp_get_wtime();
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
    {
        double x,partial_sum = 0.0;
        int init = num_steps_perthread * omp_get_thread_num();
        std::cout << init <<"\n";

        for (int i = init;i< init+num_steps_perthread; i++){
            x = (i+0.5)*step;
            partial_sum += 4.0/(1.0+x*x);
        }
        sum += partial_sum;// this line data race
    }
    pi = step * sum;
    double time = omp_get_wtime() - start_time;
    std::cout << pi << " computed in " << time;


    return 0;
}
```

so before asking questions, here are my assumption about openMP parallel construct(correct me if I am wrong):

- any variable in the scope of the construct is a local thread variable.
- any variable outside the scope is shared.
- we can control the status of variables via some keyword(for now I am not aware of the exact syntax)

when I run the program I get the expected output but normally(IMO) I shouldn't, because I have written a data race(it's indicated in the code). the variable sum is written to by multiple thread.

I think that one possible scenario is, for example, thread number 2 write to sum and update it's value, but before the processor update the entire hierarchy of memory locations(level of caches and RAM) another thread(let's say thread 4) pick up the old value and update it with it's partial sum. So we won't have an addition but an overwrite.

1) sum = 0
2) thread 2 add it's partial_sum. let's say +2. sum =2 but other memory locations still hold the old value.
3) thread 4 pick the old value and add to it.
4) all memory locations of sum are updated with thread 2 is result.
5) the update of the result of thread 4 overwrite the value.

**Questions:**

- so is My mental model correct?
- or does openMP add implicit synchronizations?
- are my assumptions true?
- are there any implicit addition done by openMP?

**Note :** I am aware of work-sharing in openMP, it's just the method of the tutorial that imposed this kind of solution.

Comment: Yes, this is undefined behavior due to unsynchronized, non-atomic, non-readonly access to a shared object from multiple threads. No, undefined behavior does not require unexpected results. It requires *nothing*.

Comment: It is really hard for a data race to occur in this particular case. The update to the shared variable happens only at the end of the computation and takes several CPU cycles only. The threads are usually de-synchronised in time by much more than that. Data races are random events and the probability for them to occur is proportional to the frequency of (possibly) overlapping memory accesses.